# Removing a widget with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to remove an `Image` widget after its animation is complete. 
So far I have managed to animate the widget and then call the `animation_complete` method after the animation ends. Unfortunately, the widget is not removed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class ShootButton(Widget):
    def bullet_fly(self):
        def animation_complete(animation, widget):
            print "removing animation"
            self.remove_widget(widget=bullet1)


        with self.canvas:
            bullet1 = Image(source='bullet.png', pos = (100,200))
            animation1 = Animation(pos=(200, 300))
            animation1.start(bullet1)
            animation1.bind(on_complete=animation_complete)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to use the canvas to add an animation but add the widget directly using `add_widget()` and then remove it with `remove_widget()`. In your initial case `bullet1` is not the children of `ShootButton`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.animation import Animation


Window.size = (360, 640)

class ShootButton(Widget):
    def bullet_fly(self):
        def animation_complete(animation, widget):
            self.remove_widget(widget)
        bullet1 = Image(source='bullet.png', pos = (100,200))
        self.add_widget(bullet1)
        animation1 = Animation(pos=(200, 300))
        animation1.start(bullet1)
        animation1.bind(on_complete=animation_complete)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        button = ShootButton()
        button.bullet_fly()
        return button


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```